# The expectation of residual sum of squares when expectation of regression mean response doesn't equal to true mean response

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, self-learning, statistical-inference, regression

Textbook Applied Linear Statistical Models (5th edition) by Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter, and Li
In Page 359, equation (9.12) states:

$$\sum{E(y_i - \hat{y_i})^2} = \sum{(E(\hat{y_i}) - u_i)^2}+(n-p)\sigma^2$$

$u_i$ is the true mean response for observation i

$\hat{y_i}$ is the regression mean response for observation i

$\sigma^2$ is the variance of $y$

$p$ is the number of parameters in the linear regression

It is given that$$\sum{\sigma^2(\hat{y_i})}= p\sigma^2$$

In this case $E(\hat{y_i})$ is not necessarily equal to $u_i$.

No proof is given for equation 9.12, so I took a stab at it but I couldn't finish the proof. The following is what I got:

$$\sum{E(y_i - \hat{y_i})^2}$$
$$=\sum{E(y_i - u_i + u_i -\hat{y_i})^2}$$
$$=\sum{E((y_i-u_i)^2)+2E(y_i - u_i)(u_i -\hat{y_i})+E((u_i -\hat{y_i})^2)}$$
$$=\sum(\sigma^2+2E(y_iui)-2E(u_i^2)-2E(y_i\hat{y_i})+2E(u_i\hat{y_i})+E(u_i^2)-2E(u_i\hat{y_i}) + E(\hat{y_i}^2))$$
$$=\sum(\sigma^2 + 2u_i^2 -2u_i^2-2E(yi\hat{y_i})+E(u_i^2)+E(\hat{y_i}^2))$$
$$=\sum(\sigma^2-2E(yi\hat{y_i})+E(u_i^2)+E(\hat{y_i}^2))$$
$$=\sum(\sigma^2-2E(yi\hat{y_i})+E(u_i^2)+E^2(\hat{y_i})+\sigma^2(\hat{y_i}))$$
$$=\sum(\sigma^2-2E(yi\hat{y_i})+\sigma^2(\hat{y_i})+2E(u_i\hat{y_i})+E(u_i^2)+E^2(\hat{y_i})-2E(u_i\hat{y_i}))$$
$$=\sum(\sigma^2-2E(yi\hat{y_i})+\sigma^2(\hat{y_i})+2E(u_i\hat{y_i})+(E(\hat{y_i}) - u_i)^2)$$
$$=n\sigma^2+p\sigma^2+\sum{(E(\hat{y_i}) -u_i)^2}-2\sum{(E(yi\hat{y_i})-E(u_i\hat{y_i}))}$$

Now compare the last result with the right hand of 9.12 equation, I need to prove that 
$$2\sum{(E(yi\hat{y_i})-E(u_i\hat{y_i}))}=2p\sigma^2$$
so basically I need to show $$\sum{E(\hat{y_i}(y_i-u_i))}=p\sigma^2$$
but I don't know how to do that

Comment: The mean is usually just a number i.e. $\hat{y_i} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n y_i$ and in fact you should drop the $i$. If this is the case then you can extract the constant out of the exception due to linearity $$\mathbb{E}(ax) = a\mathbb{E}(x)$$